# Stacked bar chart overwhelmed by one value

Tags: flot, data-visualization

I'm using [JQuery Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) with the stacking plugin to create a stacked bar chart of revenue over time from a number of different sources. The problem I'm running into is that there is one timepoint where one source gained revenue a couple of orders of magnitude larger than any other in the entire chart.

The end result is that this value dominates the graph, shrinking all the other bars to an unusable height. I can set a max height on the graph, but then you lose being able to visualize the outstanding value.

Is there any best practice in data visualization to address a situation like this? Some flot option/plugin that could help? Or a library that would handle the situation in a way better than flot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain about financial plots, but in scientific plotting, to emphasize data closer to 0, a logarithmic scaled axis is frequently used.  Unlike a linear scaled axis where each equally spaced tick represents a `+N`, in a log scaled axis each equally spaced tick represents an order of magnitude increase.  The simplest case is an exponential increase where the axis goes `0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc...`

For instance here's the same bar graph with a linear and log scaled axis:

[image]

Here's the flot code I used to generate this (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sRGhh/1/)):

```
$(function() {

    var series = {data: [[0, 0.1], [1, 1], [2, 10], [3, 100000]],
                  lines: {show: false},
                  bars: {show: true}}

    $.plot("#linear", [ series ]);

    $.plot("#log", [ series ], {
        yaxis: {
            min: 0.1,
            max: 150000,
            ticks: [[0.1,"0.1"], 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000],
            transform: function (v) { 
                return (v == 0) ? Math.log(0.0001) : Math.log(v); 
            },
            inverseTransform: function (v) {
                return Math.exp(v);
            }            
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, that's a great idea. It would probably be difficult to interpret a stacked bar chart over a log scale, so I would probably switch to grouped bars instead if using this. Thanks.